# Simple JWT Method Not Allowed on Django App deployed on Gcloud App Engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, gcloud, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am fairly new to django and gcloud and I am currently stuck at this issue where I am trying deploy my Django App on Gcloud App Engine. When accessing the api for getting token I got this error.

[Error when accessing API from App Engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MmHS.png)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework_simplejwt import views as jwt_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('quitnow/', include('quitnow.urls')),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path('api/token/', jwt_views.TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', jwt_views.TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

This is my urls.py. When I try to post my information to get token, the post requests doesn't return a response and hangs. I am stuck on this for days. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: As indicated in the error message, you are doing a GET and not a POST.  Doesn't that explain the problem?

Comment: 1) Your question does not show how you are calling the endpoint. 2) The endpoint requires using the HTTP method **POST** and not the HTTP method **GET**. For example: `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": "john", "password": "password"}' http://localhost:8000/api/token/`